Angular Directives Reference elements
I have a Dashboard Component with this template:
<div class="widget-container" id="dashboard-container">
    <app-my-widget id="comp1" draggable boundary="#dashboard-container">
        <p component>Test 1</p>
    </app-my-widget>
</div> 

As you can see we have a component app-my-widget that have a directive draggable
This is the app-my-widget html:
<div class="widget-container">
    <div class="drag-handle" dragging-handler></div>
    <div class="content">
        <ng-content select="[component]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="resize-handle" resize-handler></div>
</div>

This is my app-widget-component referencing the Two Directives:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-widget',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  hostDirectives: [
    {
      directive: DraggableDirective,
      inputs: ['boundary'],
    },
    {
      directive: DraggingHandlerDirective
    },
  ],
  templateUrl: './my-widget.component.html',
  styleUrl: './my-widget.component.scss'
})

My problem is the following I have a second directive dragging-handler with just this code:
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}
I need from the draggable Directive reference the div element with the Directive dragging-handler  so my code should be something like this:
@ContentChild(DraggingHandlerDirective) handle!: DraggingHandlerDirective;
  handleElement!: HTMLElement;

But handle is always undefined. What I'm missing here?

This is probably not the best but I'm tired of spending 2 days to make this work so what I did was:
this.element = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
this.handleElement = (this.element).querySelector('.drag-handle');

And this worked perfectly fine. Thanks all for your suggestions.

You can just use ViewChild to access the directive, from the other directive. Because the directive is present in the hostDirectives, the handler, is a child element in the view, not the content.
@Directive({ ... })
export class DraggableDirective {
    @ViewChild(DraggingHandlerDirective) handle!: DraggingHandlerDirective;
    handleElement!: HTMLElement;
    ...
}

Also we do not need to second definition of draggable directive in the dashboard component, since you already added it to the host listeners.
<div class="widget-container" id="dashboard-container">
    <app-my-widget id="comp1" boundary="#dashboard-container">
        <p component>Test 1</p>
    </app-my-widget>
</div>  


Thanks @NarenMurali I made your suggested changes:
@ViewChild(DraggingHandlerDirective) handle!: DraggingHandlerDirective;
handleElement!: HTMLElement;
And removed the definition from dashboard, and still the handle variable is undefined.

@JoseRaulPerera could you replicate the issue on this stackblitz and update on the question, just the minimal reproducible code is needed
